# How do I replace one GET parameter with another?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a site with an application that people installed on their computer. The application accesses my site with the get parameter `param`: `mysite.com?param=sometext`.

Due to a recent upgrade and an integration with another system, my site now needs the parameter `p`: `mysite.com?p=sometext`. I need the page to change the parameter without refreshing the page (when a user sends the `param` parameter I need it converted to the `p` parameter).

Is there any way to do this with jQuery/AJAX? Maybe something else?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you check server side for `param` if `p` was empty? Would be a lot easier and much less hacky.

Comment: I need a client side script. Hacky is all I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery and AJAX are client-side technologies. The limitation of your installed base of users is presumably that you can't change anything at the client side without persuading everyone to reinstall the application; in that case these can't help you.

Since you can't change the requests coming from the client app, the only thing you can do is make the server-side respond to `param=x` the same as it would for `p=x`. That would seem to be easiest to do by changing the script that receives the request to allow either one of the parameter names to be used interchangeably.

If you can't change the script either, about your only remaining tactic would be to alter the request at the web server level. For example if you were using Apache with mod_rewrite, you could add to the config something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param=([^&]+)
RewriteRule /myscriptpath /myscriptpath?p=%1
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most usable answer in practice, since it's not supported everywhere, BUT all modern browser has support for a method called `pushState`. That method can update the url in the adressbar without forcing the page to reload.

Here is a table of where it's supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate

And if you want to read more about how to use it, you can start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history